# find first and last dates from log data in azure table storage

Tags: c#-4.0, date, logging, duration, azure-table-storage

I have about 3 million rows of data in a azure table storage which come from log files.  Each row in the table is a detection of a certain event (this may be 1 or 100 rows of data per client, we don't know till its there) and there is a number of different events.

For each event i need to find the duration of the event from the timestamp of each row for each client.  If there is a gap between end and start time, it would be count as a new event. EventId is the Partition Key for the row, and a composite key of timestamp to epoch and client ID make up the rowKey.

The Azure Table Storage Looks like the following, with some example data:

```
PartitionKey     RowKey          ClientId     Epoch       Additional
1                1370966492_1    1            1370969592  34
1                1370967792_1    1            1370967792  63
2                1370969592_1    1            1370969592  34
1                1370972592_1    2            1370972592  47
1                1370973542_1    1            1370969592  44
2                1370976562_1    1            1370976562  18
1                1370978592_1    2            1370978592  92
3                1370981542_1    2            1370981542  34
2                1370982562_1    1            1370982562  37
1                1370982592_1    1            1370982592  73
```

And the output i need is (example not related to data above:

```
EventId    ClientId    StartTime    EndTime      Max(additional)
1          1           1370966492   1370973492   78
1          2           1370967834   1370979536   29
```

What would be the most efficient way of processing the data? would it to be to keep the data in Table Storage? once i have processed these logs it is possible to change the import procedure to the Table Storage if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a different format for your date in the RowKey. The problem is that the RowKey and PartitionKey are both string then the comparison is always OrdinalCase. You must provide a format that represent all dates with the same number of characters and the OrdinalCase comparison be the same of the Dates comparison. EX: 20130805122200 (yyyyMMddhhmmss).

The other thing is that TableStorage services work as follow:
- Search for a given PartitionKey
- For each Partition that match search for a given RowKey
- For each Entity that match search for any Other criteria

Then in the example above you use the Date and the Event in the RowKey. If you always search by dates i recommend you that you include this property in the PartitionKey too.